# Disable firewall service

Tags: rhel, iptables, firewall

How do I disable the firewall in RHEL 6.8?
I tried

```
service iptables stop
chkconfig iptables off
service ip6tables stop
chkconfig iptables off
```

I can see that the service is off and disabled by running:

```
service iptables status
chkconfig --list iptables
```

The problem is that after I reboot the system iptables starts again. I grepped for "iptables" in /etc/init.d but did not find anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I have access to both RHEL 6.9 systems and CentOS 6.9 systems and while both have internet access and while I don't want to boot them with the firewall turned off to test, have you tried running the system-config-firewall-tui command?  Perhaps it does something slightly different than what chkconfig does (i.e. see /etc/sysconfig/system-config-firewall).

```
 $ sudo system-config-firewall-tui
```

It starts a console-gui that opens with an option to disable:

```
system-config-firewall

           ┌───────────┤ Firewall Configuration ├───────────┐
           │                                                │
           │ A firewall protects against unauthorized       │
           │ network intrusions. Enabling a firewall blocks │
           │ all incoming connections. Disabling a firewall │
           │ allows all connections and is not recommended. │
           │                                                │
           │             Firewall: [*] Enabled              │
           │                                                │
           │   ┌────┐      ┌───────────┐      ┌────────┐    │
           │   │ OK │      │ Customize │      │ Cancel │    │
           │   └────┘      └───────────┘      └────────┘    │
           │                                                │
           │                                                │
           └────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Perhaps you should see if your system has this command and determine if it does what you desire.